What is the difference between tomographically complete and informational complete?
As I understand, a set of effects $\mathcal{E}\subset\mathcal{E}(\mathcal{H})$ are called informational complete if given $\sigma \in \mathcal{T}\mathcal(H)$, $\operatorname{tr}[\sigma E]=0$ for all $E\in\mathcal{E}$, then $\sigma=0$.
This is also equivalent to: if $\operatorname{tr}[\sigma_1 E]=\operatorname{tr}[\sigma_2 E]$ for all $E\in\mathcal{E}$ then  $\sigma_1=\sigma_2$.
However, if we are performing state tomography, then our state is not a general operator in the trace class. Rather, it has trace one.
In other words, now $\rho\in\mathcal{S}(\mathcal{H})\subset \mathcal{T}(\mathcal{H})$, where $\mathcal{S}(\mathcal{H}):=\{\rho\in \mathcal{T}(\mathcal{H})\,|\,\rho\ge 0,\,\operatorname{tr}[\rho]=1\}$.
Therefore, for the definition of tomographical completeness, can we replace $\mathcal{T}(\mathcal{H})$ with $\mathcal{S}(\mathcal{H})$ in the definition of informational completeness?
In other words, can we now define tomographical completeness as: given $\rho_1, \rho_2 \in \mathcal{S}(\mathcal{H})$
if $\operatorname{tr}[\rho_1 E]=\operatorname{tr}[\rho_2 E]$ for all $E\in\mathcal{E}$ then  $\rho_1=\rho_2$?

Yes it's the same thing. If a set of effects $\{E_i\}_i$ linearly spans the set of all density matrices (i.e. the unit-trace positive semidefinite operators) then it also spans all operators. Trivially because any operator can be written as a linear combination of density matrices.
In practice, the terms "tomographically complete" and "informationally complete" are typically used as synonyms in the literature.

Do you mean that whether it is $\sigma \in \mathcal{T}(H)$ or $\sigma \in \mathcal{S}(\mathcal{H})$ does not make any difference? My gut feeling is that it does make a difference as $\sigma \in \mathcal{S}(\mathcal{H})$ has $d^2 - 1$ degrees of freedom while $\sigma \in \mathcal{T}(\mathcal{H})$ has $d^2$ degrees of freedom, where $d$ is the dimension of the Hilbert space. Hence, tomographical completeness differs from informational completeness in that it requires one less effect.

I mean that (at least in finite dimensions) a set of effects spans all density matrices iff it spans all operators. Think of a qubit: you can't span all qubit states without spanning $I,X,Y,Z$, and thus all Hermitian operators. Formally, any operator decomposes uniquely in terms of 2 Hermitians, any Hermitian decomposes as $H=P-Q$ with $P,Q\ge0$, and any PSD is a scalar multiple of a density matrix. Thus any linear operator is a linear combination of density matrices

A qubit has the density operator $\rho = \frac{I + xX + yY + zZ}{2}$ and hence has only three degrees of freedom. So, aren't the effects ${\Pi_1, \Pi_2, \Pi_3} = {\frac{I+X}{2}, \frac{I+Y}{2}, \frac{I+Z}{2}}$ tomographically complete? Solving the equations $\operatorname{tr}[\rho \Pi_k] = p_k, \quad k=1,2,3$ can uniquely determine the qubit $\rho$. However, informational completeness requires four effects.

@Godfly666 that's true, though that set of effects wouldn't represent a physical measurement due to the lack of normalisation: you don't have $\sum_i \Pi_i=I$. I guess the proper way to state this is then that there is no difference between informational and  tomographic completeness as you defined them, for any set of effects that forms a POVM. But if you're just going for the mathematical abstraction, sure, you can have a set of effects which span a basis of traceless Hermitians for the space, but not the identity

In a typical physical experiment, we don't perform a single-setting measurement where there is a single POVM. Instead, we use multiple measurement settings, each of which is a POVM.  For example, to measure a qubit, we usually don't use the SIC-POVM with four elements. Instead, we use three measurement settings ${\frac{1\pm X}{2}}$, ${\frac{1\pm Y}{2}}$, ${\frac{1\pm Z}{2}}$. That's where my doubt comes from.

I guess we still need at least 4 effects even if they don't form a POVM. This is because, in physical experiments, we measure the counts rather than the probabilities themselves. If we want to normalize the counts to the probabilites, we then need one more effect to solve for the total number of counts. Therefore, although an n-qubit system has $4^n - 1$ degrees of freedom, we still need $4^n$ effects to perform tomography. In this sense, my problem is solved :) thank you.

I wouldn't say that, no. A "typical physical experiment" can very well use single-setting measurements with a single POVM. See eg https://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.132.160802, https://journals.aps.org/prxquantum/abstract/10.1103/PRXQuantum.3.040310, among many other references. Yes, the "standard tomography scheme" that you'll find discussed in Nielsen and Chuang involves measuring in 3 bases, but that's by no means a requirement. The minimal tomographically/informationally complete POVM has 4 outcomes. See eg SIC-POVMs. Or $4^n$ for $n$-qubit systems

I think single-setting measurement is relatively a new thing. The earliest reference I can find is Phys. Rev. A 78, 042338 (2008). If you look at recent papers on novel state tomography schemes, the majority of them use multiple settings. In this sense, single-setting measurements are unusual, which I think makes sense since single-setting measurements are more resource-consuming.

@Godfly666 I agree that it's becoming more fashionable recently, yes. But it's not true that it's more time-consuming. Single-setting measurements are often more convenient in practice as they don't require changing experimental apparatus, and you can also prove that the performance in terms of sampling statistics required to reach an additive accuracy is not worse. Eg SIC-POVMs (single-setting 4-outcome POVMs) are optimal from this perspective, and provide estimators with the same variance as MUBs (essentially the standard measurement scheme that uses PVMs in X,Y,Z)

I said they are resource-consuming, not time-consuming. Basically, single setting measurements exchange resources for time. They need more detectors but less repetitions. Now we are on the same page. It was a nice discussion with you!
